# Import.Jar file in android gives error

Tags: android

First I have written small in java and then exported to .jar file 
here is the Java code

```
package de.vogella.eclipse.ide.first;

public class MyFirstClass {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello Eclipse!");

    }

}
```

then converted to "myfile.jar" its working fine("Hello Eclipse!")
I am calling "myfile.jar" file in android application but not able to get the "MyFirstClass" in android application,
Android code main.java

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import de.vogella.eclipse.ide.first.*;  // Here I imported jar file

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you added the .jar file to the project through the menu Project->Properties->Java Build PATH?

Comment: Yes I added but its not working

Comment: Post whatever error you are getting.

Comment: I am calling like this "de.vogella.eclipse.ide.first.MyFirstClass abc= new MyFirstClass();
 System.out.println("abc"+abc);" but output is"abcde.vogella.eclipse.ide.first.MyFirstClass@168be1b"

Answer (score 0):

This tutorial will help you

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/jar-for-android/

Hope this help

Comment: Yes I placed but its not working or give some easy example to call classes and methods inside android application :-(